# Why Cross-Origin Blocked Request with typescript angular 2..?

Tags: angular, promise, angular2-services, angular-http, angular2-observables

I'm getting "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" exception as mentioned below while accessing rest api end point through Angular 2 typescript. I'm trying to learn angular 2, Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://xxxxxxxxx.com/place/countries. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

My service class is as below:-

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Headers, Response, Http } from '@angular/http';

    import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
    //import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

    import { HeaderOption } from '../model/header-option.component';
    import { Country } from '../model/country.component';

    import { BRAND_HEADERS, LEFT_HEADERS, HOME, PROFILE, LOGOUT, LOGIN} from './header-mock';

    @Injectable()
    export class HeaderService {
        private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});
        private countriesUrl = 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/place/countries';

        constructor(private http: Http) {}

        getCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {
             //return this.http.get(this.countriesUrl, {headers: this.headers}).toPromise().then(response => response.json().records as Country[]).catch(this.handleError);
             //return this.http.get(this.countriesUrl, this.headers).map((res:Response) => res.json()).catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
             return this.http.get(this.countriesUrl, this.headers).map((response: Response) => <Country[]> response.json()).do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));
          }

        private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
          console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
          return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
        }

        getBrand():HeaderOption{
            return BRAND_HEADERS;
        }
        getLeftHeader():HeaderOption[]{
            return LEFT_HEADERS;
        }


        getHomeLink():HeaderOption{
            return HOME;
        }
        getProfileLink():HeaderOption{
            return PROFILE;
        }
        getLogoutLink():HeaderOption{
            return LOGOUT;
        }
        getLoginLink():HeaderOption{
            return LOGIN;
        }
    }
```

Comment: its not client.. its the server blocking cross origin request... fix it on server, client is only showing the error which server returned

Comment: why server blocking it, when plan URL accessible from browser. what needs to be done at server side to enable it..?

Comment: `why server blocking it` because that's what CORS is all about

Comment: by default cors is not enabled by any server,, you will have to write code to do that... depending on which language your server is written, google it and you should get a solution. But first try to understand what is CORS and why it is good to have it disabled by default

Answer (score 0):

If you have a node/express app you have to **enable CORS** :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
    Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
```

https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Answer (score 0):

your problem is server side. the server doesn't allow the request from the browser with your domain i assume "localhost:4200" you can add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to your server response header .https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin
and if you are just testing and learning you can use this add-on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/ to your firefox browser or others for other browsers.